# Any way I can read a SQL item ID, and add a line with a new value to the same item ID?

Tags: sql, postgresql, dspace

If any of you guys know DSpace and the DB behind it, you know you can change almost any of the dc.properties there.

All the documents that are already on DSpace were submitted missing the dc.rights field. I've been trying it out, and I know that I can add the field just by adding a new line with the values on the DB.

Doing it one by one would be time consuming, and I'm wondering if it's possible to do a query that reads the item_id column and for each different item_id, insert a line containing that same item_id and the desired values for the "metadata_field_id" and "text_value" columns.

If I was programming, I'd probably do a "for each" loop, but not sure if this is the way to go for sql.

Anyone with a hint on how to accomplish this?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

INSERT INTO ... SELECT ... is probably what you are looking for and it will process the data in one step (if I understood correctly what you want to achieve). Something like:

```
INSERT INTO some_table (item_id, metadata_field_id, text_value)
SELECT item_id, 'new_metadata', 'new_text_value'
FROM some_table;
```

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, you can also use the CSV exporter and uploader to do these kinds of batch edits on multiple items. Download your items in the CSV, add a column for dc.rights, re-upload and you're done.